# Unable to use charset cp1256 in emacs 23

Tags: emacs, encoding, arabic

I'm trying to open a file in Emacs 23.1 which I believe to be encoded in cp1256 (a.k.a. windows-1256, Arabic). However, when using 'C-x RET c' (universal-coding-system-argument) to select an encoding before opening the file, I am told that there is no match for either of these, and in the *Completions* buffer, I can see that cp125[0-578] are all represented, but no cp1256. I found the file $emacs/etc/charsets/CP1256.map, and when I call 'M-x list-character-sets', cp1256 is present. I believe the issue is that Mule is not aware of this charmap; how to I get it to use that file?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the `windows-1256` instead of the `cp1256`?

Also, you can also try to open your file with default / autodetected encoding, then re-load the file with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> : do you have either of these encodings `windows-1256` / `cp1256`?

Comment: There is no variation of cp1256, windows-1256, or any capitalization or punctuation thereof. I tried all the various C-x RET * combinations, and none of these had the desired encoding.